# Accidentally set radio to USA band on Moto G4+, no way to revert it back

Tags: cellular-radio, motorola-moto-g-4g, baseband

I have Moto G4+ and I was playing around with `*#*#4636#*#*` and accidentally set the radio band to USA Band. Now there's no way of changing it back, so now I can't even connect to a network, let alone use data.

I've searched for this issue and it appears that there were other people with the problem, but all of them didn't have answers. The only possible answer was to flash the ROM again, but there was no confirmation of it having worked.

And anyway my phone isn't rooted, and I don't want to root, since it is new, as well as the fact that it's not easy for the Moto G4+.

Comment: If you were able to set, it gonna be way to reset :)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way. When you dial that code, and you click on select radio band from the 3 dot menu, the only one option: USA. I guess there is a default option, but there is no button for setting that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have three options here:

1. Bring the phone to service center if your warranty is active. This is the most harmless way.
2. Flash the stock radio or complete stock image.
3. Hard reset the phone with ##786# code. However, you need MSL (master security lock) which you should obtain from seller/carrier, which makes this way a bit cumbersome. More on this [here](https://androidforums.com/threads/accidentally-set-radio-to-usa-band.368870/#post-3399643).

Answer (score -1):

Just flash the Moto G4 QCN file using QPST Tool and it will be ok. Neither your warranty will be void as you have to change your baseband as your older baseband has by default take USA band, so it won't be possible to rectify it without changing its baseband by flashing the proper QCN file of Moto G4.

Remember, if your phone is in Nougat, then you have to manually downgrade it to Marshmallow and then again upgrade with OTA. The process is a bit tricky as QCN will change your IMEI number and you have to write your original IMEI with a hex editor in the QCN file which you have saved, and you have to reflash it to restore the original IMEI and SIM functionality.